# Show that $A^{*}\partial g(A\bar{x})\subseteq \partial(g \circ A)(\bar{x})$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that $g: Y \rightarrow ]-\infty,+\infty]$ and let $A: X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator (i.e., an $m \times n$ matrix if X and Y are $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively). Let $\bar{x}\in X$ be such that $A\bar{x}\in \operatorname{dom} g$. Show that $A^{*}\partial g(A\bar{x})\subseteq \partial(g \circ A)(\bar{x})$, where $A^{*}: Y \rightarrow X$ stands for the adjoint operator (i.e., transpose matrix) of A.

This is what I have so far, but I feel like my conclusion does not follow. Looking for suggestions to improve this proof. Thank you.

\begin{align}
v\in A^{*}\partial g(A\bar{x})&\iff g(A\bar{x})+\langle vA^{*},x-A\bar{x}\rangle\leq g(A\bar{x})\;\;\;(\forall A,x\in \operatorname{dom}(g))\\
&\iff g(A\bar{x})+ vA^{*}x- vA^{*}A\bar{x}\leq g(A\bar{x})\\
&\iff (g \circ A)(\bar{x})+\langle vA^{*},x-\bar{x}\rangle\leq(g \circ A)(x)\\
&\iff v\in\partial(g \circ A)(\bar{x}).
\end{align}

Comment: The claim works for affine operators, not just linear. Also, I don't think you don't need $A\bar{x} \in \mathrm{dom} g$.  There are multiple problems (typographic, semantic, logic) with your writing. For example, what do you mean by $\forall A ...$. Isn't $A$ already fixed in your hypothesis, and in the LHS of your equivalences (which are btw false) ?

Comment: The reverse inclusion doesn't hold automatically, but a mild assumption like $\mathrm{Im }L \cap \text{int dom }g \ne \emptyset$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be euclidean spaces (for simplicity of the exposition), $g: X \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ be convex and $A : Y \rightarrow X $ be affine, say $Ax \equiv Lx + \text{cte}$, where $L : Y \rightarrow X$ is linear. Finally, let $x \in Y$. We'll show that  $\partial (g \circ A)(x) \supseteq L^* \partial g(A(x))$.

Indeed, let $v \in \partial L^* \partial g(A(x))$. Then there exists $u \in \partial g(A(x))$ such that $ v = L^*u$. Now for any $ z \in Y$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(g \circ A)(x) + \langle v, z - x\rangle &= g(A(x)) + \langle L^*u, z - x\rangle\\
&= g(A(x) + \langle u, Lz - Lx\rangle\\
&= g(A(x)) + \langle u, Az - Ax\rangle\\
&\le g(A(z)),\text{ since }u \in \partial g(A(x))\\
&= (g \circ A)(z).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus $v \in \partial (g \circ A)(x)$, and we're done.